# Trying to profile a glmer.nb model. Error: theta size mismatch when nAGQ=0

Tags: r, convergence, lme4-nlme

I am trying to compute confidence intervals for my model.

reproducable example:

```
require(MASS)
require(lme4)
require(data.table)
set.seed(105)
n = 1000
dd = data.table()
mu = 30
g <- rpois(n, 2) + 1
y <- c(rnbinom(n, mu = 20+ 4*g, size = 0.5))
f3 <- c(rgamma(n,shape=g,scale=y**2/10) + 
          rpois(n,g)*10000*rnorm(n,y) + 
          rnbinom(n,mu = mean(g),size=0.5))
dd <- data.table(y=y, g=g, f3:=scale(f3))
m.nb <- glmer.nb(y ~ poly(f3,2) + (1|g), data=dd, 
                 verbose=TRUE, nAGQ=0)
profile(m.nb) 
# (4!=1)
# Error: theta size mismatch
```

Setting nAGQ=1 fixes this issue. However my real data is very large and I want to be able to work with an nAGQ=0 model while the nAGQ>=0 model converges.